# Importing a dll module in python3.8

Tags: windows, ctypes, dllimport, python-3.8

I am trying to write a module in C++ and to compile it with mingw32 as an dynamic library to use it in Python.

`test.cpp`

```cpp
int square(int x)
{
    return x * x;
}
```

Compiling to dll:

```
g++ -c test.cpp -o test.o
g++ test.o -shared test.dll
```

In the same directory, I have `test.py` where I want to call the function written in C++

`test.py`

```py
import os
import ctypes
from ctypes.util import find_library

os.add_dll_directory(os.getcwd())
print(os.getcwd())

print(find_library("test.dll"))

name = find_library("test.dll")
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
lib.square(3)
```

As you can see, I have already tried to include my workspace directory to the DLL search path. However, the interpreter is still unable to find the module, I have also already tried to use only `"test"`.

Output:

```
{workspacedirectory}
test.dll
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary(name)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 447, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "C:\...\Python\Python38\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 369, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
FileNotFoundError: Could not find module 'test.dll'. Try using the full path with constructor syntax.
```

So the line `find_library("test.dll")` is able to find the module, but it does not get found, when I want to load it.

Comment: What happens if you manually hardcode the full path to the DLL?

Comment: Probably it's the dependencies that can't be located, the runtime library.

Comment: If it's in the same directory, just do `ctypes.CDLL('./test')`.  No need for `find_library` or `LoadLibrary`.

Comment: Also be aware `ctypes` interfaces to C interfaces, not C++, so either compile as C, or use `extern "C"` on your exported functions.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica, yes I already tried it, but it didn't work either

Comment: What error did it give?

Comment: @MarkTolonen after adding a header file where I declared my function in an `external "C"`-block and compiling it with gcc, it worked. Thank you very much.
I am only still wondering, in which case I should use `find_library`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica the same error, only with the full path. This was not the problem, I compiled the dll as C++, not as C.

Comment: I suppose if it isn't in the same directory, `find_library` could be useful, but for my use cases, I've never had to use it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen again, thank you very much, it was a huge help to me